# Reading object returned from firestore in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read a movie object that's being pulled from a firebase firestore. All the data seems to be entered correctly. Below is a code snippet where I pull the movies and am just trying to reference and log the values so I can see what they are.

```js
const savedMovies = await getDocs(collection(db,"users/"+currentUserID+"/savedmovies"));
savedMovies.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  console.log(doc.Title);
  console.log(doc.data().Title);
  console.log("movie is "+doc.movie.Title);
  console.log(movie.Title);
});
```

doc.id and doc.data() return what I'm expecting but I can't seem to reference the specific values in these entries. The bottom 4 *console.log*'s either error or return undefined. Below is a photo of what doc.data() shows as in the console.

[image: Image snip from the console for doc.data()]

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? Apologies if this is a dumb question and thanks for reading!

Comment: `doc.data().movie.Title` seems to be what you're after. I'd recommend only calling `doc.data()` once and saving it to a variable, eg `const { movie } = doc.data(); console.log(movie.Title)`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks a bunch for your time Phil!